# how to uninstall java developer package on mac

Tags: java, macos, rjb

I have some problem when I install rjb. There's no such file or directory - /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers 
I search the solution that is to install Java developer package. But maybe I install a wrong version.After I installed, there is still no that directory. So i want to uninstall it. Is there anybody can tell me how to do that. Thanks very much.